# SQL select query for particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

My table looks like below

```
tbPatientEpisode
EpisodeIDP    int
EpisodeNumber varcher
EpisodeDate   datetime
```

when try with below SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM tbPatientEpisode
```

it show me results like below image..

[image: Result]

i want data for particular date like 2013-01-22 for this i tried below SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM tbPatientEpisode where EpisodeDate  like '%2013-01-22%'
```

but it does't return any row. what wrong with my query or is there any proper way to get this kind of result..any help will be appreciate.

Comment: don't use like on date columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your column `EpisodeDate` is datetime type.
You could cast `EpisodeDate` to datetime, but it will prevent using indexes on your column, so best way I know is to compare `EpisodeDate` with two datetimes:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbPatientEpisode
where
    EpisodeDate >= convert(datetime, '20130122', 112) and 
    EpisodeDate < dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, '20130122', 112))
```

I'll explain a bit:

First, you could compare EpisodeDate to string without conversion and rely on implicit SQL Server conversion, but you should be aware of two things:

- [Priority of types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). When you comparing valus of different types, data with lower priority would be converted to type with higher priority. It's good in our case, because `varchar` have lower priorty than `datetime`, but it could prevent of using indexes when, for example, your column is `varchar` and you want compare it with `datetime`.
- You have to know how SQL server will convert your string to date. For example SQL server could recognize format YYYYMMDD easily, but in general I think it's good practice to convert data explicitly.

So it your case you could use

```
select *
FROM tbPatientEpisode
where
    EpisodeDate >= '20130122' and 
    EpisodeDate < '20130123'
```

but you have to be sure that you know what you're doing

I've not specified `dateadd(day, 1, '20130122')` and not `'20130123'` because I'm thinking about 20130122 as input parameters, so you could replace this string in my query

Answer (score 4):

Don't use like on date columns, it's not going to work.

Instead (SQL Server 2008 onwards):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbPatientEpisode 
where CAST(EpisodeDate as Date) = '2013-01-22'
```

Note: this form won't use any applicable index starting with column `EpisodeDate`

If you want to ensure any applicable index is use (and works on SQL Server 2005):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbPatientEpisode 
where EpisodeDate between = '2013-01-22 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-22 23:59:59.997'
```

Comment: `@Mitch Wheat` it show me warning like `Type date is not a defined system type.`.

Comment: @win He mentions that the query only works on SQL Server 2008 and newer, `DATE` is (afaik) not a type in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

based on execution plan, by using LIKE, system will convert all the column type to VARCHAR then only perform scan

Why there are no result return in your query? this is because system is already converted **datetime** to **nvarchar** which is something like **Jan 22 2013 10:55AM**

and this is why there are no result is return

try change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM tbPatientEpisode where EpisodeDate  like '%Jan 22 2013%'
```

this should be work fine, and below are alternative way to use LIKE, cast your episodeDate to certain format like '2013-01-22'

```
 SELECT * FROM tbPatientEpisode where CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),EpisodeDate,126) 
 like '%2013-01-22%'
```

at last i hope my explanation able to help u to understand what is exactly going on, cheer brother =)

Answer (score 0):

This answer try to explain first why `EpisodeDate  like '%2013-01-22%'` solution doesn't work, what can you do to get desired results using `like ...` (I don't recommend) and, finally, I present two solutions (with and without implicit conversions). All queries can be executed on [AdventureWorks2008R2 sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211):

```
/*
CREATE INDEX IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate
ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader(OrderDate)
*/

-- It CONVERTs datetime values to VARCHAR with style 0 {Style 0 = mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)}
-- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
SELECT  TOP(1500)
        h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),h.OrderDate,0) AS OrderDateAsVarChar40, -- Explicit conversion from DATETIME to VARCHAR(40) with style 0
        LEFT(h.OrderDate,40) AS ForcingImplicitConvertOnDateTimeColumn -- Implicit conversion because the first argument of LEFT function must be a %CHAR
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h;
/*
OrderDate               SalesOrderID OrderDateAsVarChar40 ForcingImplicitConvertOnDateTimeColumn
----------------------- ------------ -------------------- --------------------------------------
2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 43659        Jul  1 2005 12:00AM  Jul  1 2005 12:00AM
...
2005-11-19 00:00:00.000 44685        Nov 19 2005 12:00AM  Nov 19 2005 12:00AM
2005-11-20 00:00:00.000 44686        Nov 20 2005 12:00AM  Nov 20 2005 12:00AM
...
2008-07-31 00:00:00.000 75123        Jul 31 2008 12:00AM  Jul 31 2008 12:00AM
*/

-- Result: No rows
SELECT  h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
-- The syntax of LIKE operator shows that h.OrderDate must be %CHAR
-- so, SQL Server add an implicit conversion of OrderDate values from DATETIME to VARCHAR
-- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx
WHERE   h.OrderDate LIKE '%2005-11-20%'
```

Execution plan:
[image]

```
-- Result: 5 rows 
-- I get 5 rows but it's the execution plan is unoptimized (because of Index Scan; see first execution plan)
SELECT  h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE   h.OrderDate LIKE 'Nov 20 2005%';

-- Result: 5 rows 
-- I get 5 rows and the execution plan includes 
-- (1) Index Seek operator instead of Index Scan
-- (2) and implicit conversion of @1 and @2 parameters from varchar to datetime
SELECT  h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE   h.OrderDate >= '20051120' AND h.OrderDate < '20051121';
```

Execution plan:
[image]

```
-- Result: 5 rows 
-- I get 5 rows and the execution plan includes 
-- (1) Index Seek operator instead of Index Scan
-- (2) and no implicit conversion of @1 and @2 parameters
-- See Date, Time, and Timestamp Literals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710282(v=vs.85).aspx
SELECT  h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE   h.OrderDate >= {d '2005-11-20'} AND h.OrderDate < {d '2005-11-21'};
```

Execution plan:
[image]

Comment: The type of `{d '2005-11-20'}` is `datetime`: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY({d '2005-11-20'}, 'BaseType')`.